# Python web framework

Tags: python, web-frameworks

Is there a Python web framework where the Python code and the HTML code are in the same file?

Django uses templates with a special language to generate HTML. Pylons uses a kind of language whose name is Mako.

I prefer to output HTML using calls like:

```
echo('''
    HTML string
''')
```

or

```
print '''
    HTML string
'''
```

instead of special languages.

**Edit:**

Can I do something like PHP?

```
echo( '''<p>Something</p>''' )
if cond:
    echo( '''<p>Another thing 1</p>''' )
else:
    echo( '''<p>Another thing 2</p>''' )
```

Comment: You should use CGI if this is what you want.

Comment: @Rafe: CGI is a communication protocol and doesn't define how content is produced or generated.  I serve my Django apps over (Fast)CGI and they don't / can't serve content this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `print` itself you may want to rely on `cgi`.
Going for templates, the closest you can get is from webpy project's [Templator](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor)

> The web.py template language, called
>   Templetor is designed to bring the
>   power of Python to templates. Instead
>   of inventing new syntax for templates,
>   it re-uses python syntax. If you know
>   Python programming language, you will
>   be at home.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you prefer, but it's really against every best practice ever.  That being said, you can do this with django.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
dev some_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is foolish short term gain")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) template engine allows you to use pure Python in your HTML templates (see details in [the book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05)). You can also use web2py's [HTML helpers](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#HTML-Helpers) to build HTML in Python (this generates a [server-side DOM](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#Server-side-DOM-and-Parsing) that can be queried and manipulated before rendering to HTML). If desired, the template engine can be used independent of the framework (the relevant module is [/gluon/template.py](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/template.py)). If there's something in particular you want to do, feel free to ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 0):

[Divmod Nevow](https://launchpad.net/nevow) will allow you do do that with either prints or a custom Python expression-based language that allows you to embed XHTML code directly into your scripts.  However, it's beta-quality, based on [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and thus a bit unconventional, and [the main site](http://divmod.org/) for the company that develops it is down, so I can't point you at a tutorial or anything right now.  Use at your own peril.

The special syntax (called stan) syntax looks more or less like this:

```
tags.html[
    tags.head[ tags.title[ "Greetings!" ]],
    tags.body[
        tags.h1(style="font-size: large")[ "Now I will greet you:" ],
        tags.span[ "Hello, world" ]
    ]
]
```